# How can I group a flatten array in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, lodash

for below flattened array in javascript

```json
[{
  "category": "FRESH MEAT NON PI",
  "categoryId": 76,
  "subCategoryId": 12,
  "subCategory": "BEEF-THIN MEATS",
  "itemThreshold": null,
  "sellItem": "BEEF SHORT RIBS",
  "sellItemId": 980217310,
  "key": "76-12"
}, {
  "category": "FRESH MEAT NON PI",
  "categoryId": 76,
  "subCategoryId": 12,
  "subCategory": "BEEF-THIN MEATS",
  "itemThreshold": null,
  "sellItem": "BEEF T-BONE STEAK",
  "sellItemId": 12049,
  "key": "76-12"
}]
```

how can we get grouped array like below in javascript

```json
[
  {
    "id": 76,
    "categoryName": "FRESH MEAT NON PI",
    "categoryThreshold": null,
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "key": "76-10",
        "name": "BEEF-ROASTS",
        "subCategoryThreshold": null,
        "sellitems": [
          {
            "id": 508,
            "name": "DUMPED ITEM",
            "itemThreshold": 45.0,
            "edited": false,
            "rowId": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 14186,
            "name": "BEEF LOIN TENDERLOIN",
            "itemThreshold": 45.0,
            "edited": false,
            "rowId": 13
          }]
}]
}]
```

I have tried array reduce method to make group

```
      const out = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, current) => {

      // Destructure the properies from the current object
      const { categoryId, subCategory, ...rest } = current;
    
      
      acc[categoryId] = acc[categoryId] || { categoryId, subCategory: [], ...rest };
    
      
      acc[categoryId].subCategory.push(subCategory);
      
      // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
      return acc;
    }, {}));
```

how can I add sellitems as array of objects inside subcategories array of objects just like i mentioned in the output required.

Comment: where do you get the missing informations, like thresholds from?

Answer (score 2):

You could take an approach which is highly configurable for various groups per level and manipulating of data.

The advantage is to descripe a level data input and output and hand over the rest of the object to a lower level.

```js
const
    groupBy = (data, levels, references = { __: [] }) => data
        .reduce((r, o, i) => {
            levels
                .reduce((q, fn, j) => {
                    let key, data, children, rest, update;
                    ({ key, data, children, rest, update } = fn(o, q, i, j));

                    if (key === undefined) {
                        q.__.push(data);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!q[key]) {
                        q[key] = { __: [] };
                        q.__.push(q[key]._ = children ? { ...data, [children]: q[key].__ } : data);
                    }

                    update?.(o, q[key]._, q[key]);
                    o = rest;
                    return q[key];
                }, r);
            return r;
        }, references)
        .__,
    data = [
        { category: "FRESH MEAT NON PI", categoryId: 76, subCategoryId: 12, subCategory: "BEEF-THIN MEATS", itemThreshold: null, sellItem: "BEEF SHORT RIBS", sellItemId: 980217310, key: "76-12" },
        { category: "FRESH MEAT NON PI", categoryId: 76, subCategoryId: 12, subCategory: "BEEF-THIN MEATS", itemThreshold: null, sellItem: "BEEF T-BONE STEAK", sellItemId: 12049, key: "76-12" }
    ],
    levels = [
        ({ categoryId: id, category: categoryName, ...rest }) => ({ key: id, data: { id, categoryName, categoryThreshold: null }, children: 'subCategories', rest }),
        ({ subCategoryId: id, subCategory: name, key, ...rest }) => ({ key: id, data: { id, key, name, subCategoryThreshold: null }, children: 'sellitems', rest }),
        ({ itemThreshold, sellItem: name, sellItemId: id }, _, i) => ({ data: { id, name, itemThreshold, edited: false, rowId: i + 1 } })
    ],
    result = groupBy(data, levels);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```